# Force wget to use actual Google Docs file

Tags: wget, batch

I am programming in batch it shouldn't matter because i am using wget on Windows too.

I found similar question on this site [Force wget to use actual filename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77711/force-wget-to-use-actual-filename) first solution works for everyone  but why it doesn't working for me  ? I am getting following error.

```
C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\TemObv\GnuWin32\bin>wget --content-disposition 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE'

SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\TemObv\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
'http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE': Unsupported scheme.
```

Update:

```
C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\TemObv\GnuWin32\bin>wget --content-disposition "http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE&output=xls"
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\TemObv\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2012-11-20 15:11:40--  http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE&output=xls
Resolving spreadsheets.google.com... 74.125.227.102, 74.125.227.103, 74.125.227.104, ...
Connecting to spreadsheets.google.com|74.125.227.102|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE&output=xls [following]
--2012-11-20 15:11:40--  https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE&output=xls
Connecting to spreadsheets.google.com|74.125.227.102|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify spreadsheets.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to spreadsheets.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: You are using `--content-disposition` without specifying a content disposition to use.  Don't do that.

Comment: `--content-disposition` tells wget it should honor the Content-Disposition header, it does no take any argument...

Comment: so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you'd have to use double quotes (") around the url...

```
wget --content-disposition "http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE"
```

If this redirects you to https and you dont have the certificates installed you might need to issue the following instead:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition "http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE"
```

Comment: I tried that, but it goes me this error check edit.

Comment: well then just do as proposed in the error message. Your installation does not know the google certificate:
    wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition "http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AqSBI1OogE84dGN2bXRSZkZPVVRuNkMtN0p4eXpyVlE"

Comment: Man you are the GURU..... I am sure lots of people will find this helpfull. your comment solution worked Thanks alot.

Comment: I don't have 15 reps but I would've gave you +UP, is there something I can put in code where if I run code again it will override existing file ?

Comment: No problem at all... I just updated the answer...

Comment: check options -nc / -N for that...